# AngularJs ForEach Loop only Shows last Object when pushed into new Object

Tags: angularjs, foreach

I am using the `forEach` to `loop` through it `iterates` through all of the objects but only writes the last one to the new object of `log`{}.

My `Javascript`

```
$http.get('data.json').success(
   function (info) {
      var log = {};
      log.id= info.id;
      log.profile = {};

      angular.forEach(info.profile, function (value, key) {
         console.log(key,value)
         log.profile.inter = value.inter
      }, log);
      console.log(JSON.stringify(log));
   }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the reason is that you are not using an array, you need to push values into an one.

```
$http.get('data.json').success(
   function (info) {
      var log = {};
      log.id= info.id;
      log.profile = {};
      log.profile.inter = []; //definition of array

      angular.forEach(info.profile, function (value, key) {
         console.log(key,value)
         log.profile.inter.push(value.inter); //add values in array defined behind
      }, log);
      console.log(JSON.stringify(log));
   }
);
```

There are more solutions, but for now putting values in array is enough.

Comment: you cant use push with objects... ReferenceError: push is not defined

Comment: log.profile.inter = []; //definition of array in the code

Answer (score 0):

> ### Deprecation Notice
>
> The `$http` legacy promise methods `.success` and `.error` have been deprecated. Use the standard `.then` method instead.<sup>[1](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#deprecation-notice)</sup>

```
$http.get('data.json')
     .then(function onFulfilled(response) {
         var info = response.data;
         var log = {};
         log.id= info.id;
         log.profile = {};
         angular.forEach(info.profile, function (value, key) {
             console.log(key,value);
             log.profile[key] = value.inter;
         });
         console.log(JSON.stringify(log));
     }).catch ( function onRejected(response) {
         console.log("ERROR ", response.status;
     });
```

To save values into an *associative array*, use the `key` as the *property accessor*. For more information, see [MDN JavaScript Reference -- Property Accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)

```
            log.profile[key] = value.inter;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
         var log = {};
          log.id= info.id;
          log.profile = {};
          log.profile.inter = []; //definition of array

          angular.forEach(info.profile, function (value, key) {
             console.log(key,value)
//needed to add key
             log.profile[key] = {};

          }, log);
          console.log(JSON.stringify(log));
       }
```